# how to update the qty column in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#

How do I update the qty column in `datagridview` in C#? When I call this function only one column has been updated. I couldn't update more than one column.

I attached the image below. What was the problem really I got? There is a column which is named qty, you can see on the `datagridview`. When I call `update()` function one one qty column only update. I want to update all qty which entered in the `datagridview`

[image]

```
public void updatedb()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
    {
        string itmno = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string itmqty = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        //    string t = "select * from products where id=" + itmno + "";
        // Connnew.DbSearch(t);

        con.Close();
        MySqlCommand scmd = new MySqlCommand();
        scmd.Connection = con;
        scmd.CommandText = "select * from products where id in" + itmno + "";
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr;
        dr = scmd.ExecuteReader();

        string oldqty = "", newqty = "";

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            oldqty = dr[5].ToString();
            newqty = (int.Parse(oldqty) - int.Parse(itmqty)).ToString();
        }
        string t2 = ("UPDATE products SET qty = '" + newqty + "'  WHERE id = '" + itmno + "' ");

        con.Close();
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand upcmd = new MySqlCommand(t2, con);

        upcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Updateeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: do you want either your db with new values or your datagridview?

Comment: ya. when i enter the qty after press update qty shall be update

Comment: it means you want to update your db with new values?

Comment: ya sir please help me

Comment: this is field in my database      id name catid brid price qty

Comment: Do you have only two rows in the gridview? Qty of only first row is updated not the second row?

Comment: ya sir that is my problem i want to update two rows. can you fix this code to update two rows qty.please help me

Comment: The issues is in the for loop. You should not use `row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`. You should use `row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count`.